# Date insert from python to mysql "out of range" issue

Tags: python, mysql-python

I've created a mysql db with l column "Date":

```
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| datum  | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| stroom | int(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gas    | int(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| water  | int(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Yet, when I try to insert a date from a python script it returns:
Warning: Out of range value for column 'datum' at row 1

My script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime
import MySQLdb


# define strings
i = datetime.datetime.now()
mydatum = ("%s-%s-%s" % (i.day, i.month, i.year))
#mydatum = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
mystroom = open('/home/pi/textfiles/stroomverbruik.txt', 'r').read(4)
mygas =  open('/home/pi/textfiles/gasverbruik.txt', 'r').read(4)
mywater =  open('/home/pi/textfiles/waterverbruik.txt', 'r').read(4)


# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","[password]","P1" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
sql = "INSERT INTO verbruik (datum, stroom, gas, water) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)" % (mydatum, mystroom, mygas, mywater)


try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
db.close()


print mydatum
print mystroom
print mygas
print mywater
```

Is mysql expecting another date-format?
The other values are correctly stored in the database, but the date value is stored like 0000-00-00.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `mydatum = i.date()` and use parameterized query i.e.,`cursor.execute(...VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)", (mydatum, mystroom, ..))`? Note: it doesn't use string formatting (%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your Python code isn't formatting the date properly by putting it into `D-M-Y` instead of `Y-M-D` format...

Try changing

```
mydatum = ("%s-%s-%s" % (i.day, i.month, i.year))
```

to be

```
mydatum = ("%s-%s-%s" % (i.year, i.month, i.day))
```

in the Python code.

Edit to reflect solution derived from comments:

The date's `%s` had to be quoted as well, since the database had to be told to process it as a string. Modified line:

sql = "INSERT INTO verbruik (datum, stroom, gas, water) VALUES('%s',%s,%s,%s)" % (mydatum, mystroom, mygas, mywater)

Comment: Thanx, but I Tried al possible combinations and it keeps giving me the out of range warning...

Comment: @Yos Oh! I think I know what's going on. Try to quote the `%s` for the date inside your query string. Like this: `INSERT INTO verbruik (datum, stroom, gas, water) VALUES('%s',%s,%s,%s)` (note the single quotes around the first `%s`.

Comment: Thanx! That did it. Why does it need these quotes...??

Comment: That told the database to interpret the value as a string (which would then be converted into a `date`). Otherwise, it was evaluating it as a mathematical expression (i.e. 2014-10-18 = 1986) :)

Answer (score 0):

Putting the first %s in single quotes was the solution as Ruslan posted.
After doing so the date was correctly stored in the database:

```
| 0000-00-00 |   2953 |  1021 |   197 |
| 0000-00-00 |   2953 |  1021 |   197 |
| 0000-00-00 |   2953 |  1021 |   197 |
| 2014-10-18 |   2953 |  1021 |   197 |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+
347 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```